# How to set different colors for same widget type using ThemeData? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to find examples and tutorials on how to implement a `ThemeData` in flutter. Although most of them seem to implement it rather easily, I have not found any examples where one widget type (ex: Text, FlatButton, Card, etc.) are able to have multiple colors at the same time.

In my application, if i have two Strings : "enter tasks here" and "Tasks for this day - ${cardList.length}", is it possible to define a single `ThemeData` where the first string can use one color and the second string can use a different color?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post an example of how would you like to use that theme on the same Text widget?

Comment: I have added 2 pictures as an example. the first picture is dark mode toggled and the second picture is light mode toggled. In flutter how can i define a single ```ThemeData``` so that when a user is toggling dark mode, there can be certain texts which can be white colored and the other texts can be red colored? (credits to https://uppertodo.com/themes/ for the images).

Comment: You can define a light theme and a dark theme

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article that explains how to do it: [Dynamic theming with Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dynamic-theming-with-flutter-78681285d85f)

Basically, you have to create a `CustomTheme` that handles the current selected `ThemeData` and wrap your app with this `CustomTheme`. Then you could change the current selected theme from anywhere:

> - We change the theme calling    `CustomTheme.instanceOf(context).changeTheme(ourThemeKey)`.
> - The change triggers a `setState` updating the theme with the new value    inside the `CustomTheme` Stateful Widget.
>
> Due to the `setState`, `CustomTheme` rebuilds. The Inherited Widget gets
>   rebuilt as well, and since its `updateShouldNotify` returns `true` all the
>   depending widgets (`MaterialApp` in our case) are updated, resulting in
>   a UI update with the new color scheme.

With this solution you could have any number of different themes you want.

Comment: You can see the whole code in the article I mentioned, it's too much code to put in here. Maybe when I have time I could provide a shorter example with code here.

Comment: I know, that's why I explained the solution quoting the article. Feel free to provide an edit with a short code sample if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I use them this way:

First initialize theme and darktheme property in your materialApp or Create a saperate class if you wish.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primaryColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.grey,
  ),
);
```

Then use it like this where you want it:

```
Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  child: Text(
    'Text with a background color',
  ),
);
```

You can also use it to define multiple textStyles, and other Colors like accentColors also.

Answer (score 0):

You can define both a default (say light) theme and a dark theme as such (as explained [here](https://medium.com/flutter/android-dark-theme-in-flutter-9c8070b8b127))

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
);
```

Inside each `ThemeData` instance you can define `ButtonTheme` and all the rest.

Comment: but will this method allow me to specify multiple colors for multiple Strings ?

Comment: You'll have to be more precise. You can override parts of the `ThemeData.textTheme` which contains a lot of default textstyles. You could also define your own class, that encapsulates ThemeData and add your own TextStyle